# Get customer data

Tags: magento2

I have the following code that retrieve the data from a customer by its email:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as RequestHttp;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as ResponseHttp;
use Magento\Framework\Event;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\AreaList;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class CustomerApp extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository
 */
protected $_customerRepository;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
 */
protected $_customerInterface;

protected $_customInterface;


public function launch() {
    $response = $this->getCustomer();
    //return $response;
    return $this->_response;
}

public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
{
    return false;
}

protected $customer_Repository;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
 * @param Event\Manager $eventManager
 * @param AreaList $areaList
 * @param RequestHttp $request
 * @param ResponseHttp $response
 * @param ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader
 * @param State $state
 * @param Filesystem $filesystem
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
 \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository $customer_Repository,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customerInterface
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    Event\Manager $eventManager,
    AreaList $areaList,
    RequestHttp $request,
    ResponseHttp $response,
    ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader,
    State $state,
    Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository $customer_Repository,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customerInterface
) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
    $this->_areaList = $areaList;
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->_response = $response;
    $this->_configLoader = $configLoader;
    $this->_state = $state;
    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->customer_Repository = $customer_Repository;
    $this->_customerInterface = $customerInterface;
}

public function getCustomer() {

    $data = $this->customer_Repository->get("test@test.com");
    return $data;

}
}
```

The variable `$data` received get a `Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer` Object and do not know who to check if the customer exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$data->getId();
```

if ID is returned  it means that customer exsists